# InDesign scripting: How to apply sub-master to a master page?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am new to InDesign Scripting. I am trying to write a script to apply a master page (sub-master) to a master page. I am not able to figure out how to do this.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the property `appliedMaster` of your masterSpread to another masterSpread.

So basically something like (this to apply a sub master page to a main master page):

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var mainMaster = doc.masterSpreads.item("Name of Main Master");
var subMaster = doc.masterSpreads.item("Name of Sub Master");

mainMaster.appliedMaster = subMaster;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!